# NativeScript change value of label when button tapped

Tags: nativescript

Using NativeScript, I'm having trouble changing a label that's two-way binded.

Using the "model-view-model" technique, I'm able to set a variable to a value and have my label display the value upon page load.

Upon a button press, I can change the value of the variable (as indicated in the Console),but the label doesn't change its value.

Here's the Nativescript Playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=rH0lcK

I even tried passing in the "args" variable to try to set the label (by an ID), but that didn't work... but even if it did, I thought the 2-way binding would have updated the value automatically?

NOTE: I'm using JavaScript (not Angular)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please pay attention to hello-world app, which exactly demonstrates what you are looking for. Try to spend good time with docs, may be with W3Schools too in understanding the basics of JavaScript.

You are declaring a global variable `myText` inside `onButtonTap` function instead of updating the property of observable. Try

```
this.set('myText', newValue);
```

Comment: I'm not sure in which context you see $. You may check the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_data_observable_.observable#set)